# PHP cURL to pass the entire "Class Objects"?

Tags: php, class, object, post, curl

In PHP + cURL, i can pass the simple `objects` like JSON/ Array Objects but still don't know how to pass the whole `class` object.

- Lets say i DO NOT HAVE the `class file` at the destination Server. Thats why i want to tranfer via `cURL`.

Now my class sample is:

```
class MyClass {
    function sayHello() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

And the `sender.php` (on one server):

```
require_once("class.myclass.php");
$myClass = new MyClass;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://................");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('theclass' => serialize($myClass), 'username' => "abc123"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1);
echo $response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

.. but the class can not be used at the destination end, here the `receiver.php` (on another different server which do NOT HAVE the class file there):

```
$myClass = unserialize($_POST['theclass']);
echo $myClass->sayHello();
```

- Any bright idea please?
- Is it even durable?

Comment: Have you included the class (or implement an autoloader) before you `unserialize()`?

Comment: Sorry i didn't get what you mean :/ how should it be please?

Comment: Add `require_once("class.myclass.php");` before you call `unserialize($_POST['theclass']);`

Comment: your class needs to implement serializeable: http://php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php

Comment: huh :S where is `"class.myclass.php"` coming from? I am receiving that `class object` from the cURL. The actual file is not existed at that destination end.

Comment: Look at the manual for unserialize(). And perhaps the exact error you're getting is relevant.

Comment: `http_build_query()` ?

Comment: @夏期劇場 it's coming from you :\ We don't know what your class looks like or what it contains.

Comment: @itsmejodie please look the edited question above again. Thanks.

Comment: ok, like I said, just add `require_once("class.myclass.php");` to the top of receiver.php so that the class is loaded before you unserialize

Comment: but seriously it can't be, huh :S how come i can use `require_once("class.myclass.php");` unless there is a real file existed, on that receiver SERVER :S Are you serious??

Comment: You have that file in your sender.php, it needs to be accessible to the receiver.php as well.

Comment: please mister, are you kidding :S Using `cURL` normally means, passing the objects/data across different SERVERS. :S

Comment: For clarification, when you use `serialize()` you are serializing an *instance* of the class, not the class itself.  To bring the instance back from the dead (via `unserialize()`) you still need the class definition (EG. `class.myclass.php`)

Comment: @夏期劇場 There are 2 mistakes. Use my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Use [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)():

```
$postdata = array('theclass' => serialize($myClass), 'username' => "abc123");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postdata) );
```

2) Add `require_once("class.myclass.php");` to the `receiver.php`

Comment: Are you sure about step `2` on the receiver? They are not on same Server you know rite? I DO NOT have the `class.myclas.php` file on destination server. Thats why i am transferring to use it, at destination end. So how could i include it?

Comment: I am sure. Copy the file to the server.

Comment: huh, copy the file there??? :S so why should i be transferring the class via cURL anymore? :S

Comment: @夏期劇場 I explained this above. You're not transferring the class, only the object instance.

Comment: You transfer a value, not a class definition (just copy the file, do it once, and see what you get).

Comment: No i want to transfer the whole class definition and use it at the destination end, as i ofcourse don't have the class there.

Comment: PHP Documentation: `You should include the file classa.inc on all of your pages` http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php If you want to make unusual things, so just transfer the definition as a string and `eval()` it, but DO NOT DO LIKE THAT.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this class for fast entry

```
<?php 
class cURL { 
var $headers; 
var $user_agent; 
var $compression; 
var $cookie_file; 
var $proxy; 
function cURL($cookies=TRUE,$cookie='cookies.txt',$compression='gzip',$proxy='') { 
    $this->headers[] = 'Accept: image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg'; 
    $this->headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive'; 
    $this->headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'; 
    $this->user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR       1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0)'; 
    $this->compression=$compression; 
    $this->proxy=$proxy; 
    $this->cookies=$cookies; 
    if ($this->cookies == TRUE) $this->cookie($cookie); 
} 
function cookie($cookie_file) { 
    if (file_exists($cookie_file)) { 
    $this->cookie_file=$cookie_file; 
} else { 
    fopen($cookie_file,'w') or $this->error('The cookie file could not be opened. Make   sure this directory has the correct permissions'); 
   $this->cookie_file=$cookie_file; 
   fclose($this->cookie_file); 
    } 
} 
function get($url) { 
    $process = curl_init($url); 
   curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers); 
   curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
   curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->user_agent); 
   if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this- >cookie_file); 
   if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie_file); 
    curl_setopt($process,CURLOPT_ENCODING , $this->compression); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
   if ($this->proxy) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxy); 
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
        $return = curl_exec($process); 
        curl_close($process); 
     return $return; 
} 
function post($url,$data) { 
    $process = curl_init($url); 
     curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers); 
      curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
      curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->user_agent); 
     if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this- >cookie_file); 
      if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie_file); 
      curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_ENCODING , $this->compression); 
       curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
   if ($this->proxy) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxy); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
      $return = curl_exec($process); 
   curl_close($process); 
    return $return; 
} 
    function error($error) { 
             echo "<center><div style='width:500px;border: 3px solid #FFEEFF; padding:                 3px; background-color: #FFDDFF;font-family: verdana; font-size: 10px'><b>cURL Error</b>     <br>$error</div></center>"; 
              die; 
      } 
  } 
    $cc = new cURL(); 
    $cc->get('http://www.example.com'); 
   $cc->post('http://www.example.com','foo=bar'); 
    ?>
```

[EDIT BY danbrown AT php DOT net: Includes a bugfix provided by "Anonymous" on 01-Dec-2008 @ 06:52.  Also replaced real URL with example.com as per RFC 2606.]

[EDIT BY danbrown AT php DOT net: Includes a bugfix provided by (manuel AT rankone DOT ch) on 24-NOV-09 to properly reference cURL initialization.]

Comment: sorry but how to use it?? Can it transfer the Class Objects??

Comment: can u tell the error you get when you unserialize and access the object properties?